# RestAssured - Cookies are not set for redirected request

Tags: redirect, cookies, rest-assured

I need to set cookies for redirected request (they are sent from initial request) in RestAssured.
When I’m sending GET for my url - it responds with 302 status code and `Set-Cookie` header that needs to be set for redirected request. But these cookies are missed from redirected request and I’m getting an auth error.

It successfully works in Postman, but not in REST Assured. Here’s code sample:

```
        given()
                .spec(requestSpecWithToken)
                .redirects().follow(true)
                .config(RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientConfig().reuseHttpClientInstance()))
                .when()
                .get(myEndpoint)
                .then()
                .statusCode(200); // <— error 400 as no cookies
```

Also I’ve tried without `reuseHttpClientInstance` - cookies still not set for redirected request.

Here’s example from http perspective:

```
Source Request: GET https://example1.com/url-with-redirect
Source Response: 302
Set-Cookie: CookieName1=CookieValue1; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: CookieName2=CookieValue2; Path=/
location: https://example2.org/target

Redirected Request: GET https://example2.org/target
Redirected Request Cookies: -
Redirected Response: 400
```

So how can I set cookies for redirected request inside?

**Update:**

Logs:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://example1.com/url-with-redirect
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Authorization=Bearer [..]
                Accept=*/*
                Connection=keep-alive 
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
HTTP/1.1 400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format.
Content-Length: 297
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: [..]
Date: Tue, 20 Dec 2022 19:16:27 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code><Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format.
RequestId:[..]
Time:2022-12-20T19:16:27.9906229Z</Message></Error>
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. `RestAssured.baseURI = "https://httpbin.org";given().cookies("mytest-cookie", "my-test-val").redirects().follow(true).when().queryParam("url", "https://httpbin.org/get").get("/redirect-to").then().log();`

Comment: Thanks, but it's slightly different situation - in your example cookies are set **before all requests**. But in my case cookies are set **from response with redirect**. I mean request is send -> response is received with 302 status and `Set-Cookie` -> redirected request is send without these cookies

Comment: Can you change `.then().statusCode(200);` to `the.log();` and show the full log?

Comment: I've added logs to initial post. But redirect seems is not logging.